Simplifying Meijer-G function with constant multiple argument
I have a function that can be written in terms of Meijer-G function as follow
$$G_{1,2}^{2,1}\left(cz\left|\begin{smallmatrix}1-a \\
0,1-b\end{smallmatrix}\right.\right)=\frac {1}{2\pi i} \int_L \Gamma(-s)\Gamma(a+s)\Gamma(1-b-s) (cz)^s ds$$
Is there any way I can simplify this function such that the argument becomes $z$ and not $cz$? In other words how to get rid of $c^s$? Equivalently can we write this function in terms of sum of $G_{p,q}^{\,m,n} \!\left(z \left| \begin{matrix} a_1, \dots, a_p \\ b_1, \dots, b_q \end{matrix}   \right. \right)$ or even sum of Fox's H functions $H_{p,q}^{\,m,n} \!\left[ z \left| \begin{matrix}
( a_1 , A_1 ) & ( a_2 , A_2 ) & \ldots & ( a_p , A_p ) \\
( b_1 , B_1 ) & ( b_2 , B_2 ) & \ldots & ( b_q , B_p  ) \end{matrix} \right. \right]$?
